# problem with list view in android using arraylist items

Tags: android, listview

in my app i am using a list view. The data which i want to list out are from a database of my app and an xml server database.

For example i am getting some two set of data  from server and store it in a array as follows

```
firstname = {arun, Arun, Rajesh} 
lastname  = {kumar, sundar, kannan}
```

Now again i am getting some data from my app database and store it in array as follows

```
first = {arul}
last  = {raj}
```

Now i have combined the array list together as follows

```
firstname.addAll(first);
lastname.addAll(last);
```

Now i have the output as

```
{arun, Arun, Rajesh, arul} 
{kumar, sundar, kannan, raj}
```

Now i want to list out these items as in the following image
[image]

how to do this, please help me......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you finally get all your firstname and lastname in two separate array  then it is very simple to display on ListView as you want

first create a layout which has a listview element lets us name main.xml

then create a another layout having two TextView in Horizontal layout orientation let us name mainitem.xml

so now you create a new activity then call setContentView(R.layout.main)

then retrive list view

and now create a adapter by following code

this code is in onCreate(Bundle b) method

```
ListView lv= (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview1);

        // create the grid item mapping
        String[] from = new String[] {"col_1","col_2"};
        int[] to = new int[] { R.id.firstname, R.id.secondname};

        // prepare the list of all records
        List<HashMap<String, String>> fillMaps = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        for(int i = 0; i <firstname.length && lastname.length; i++)
        {
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            map.put("col_1",firstname[i]);
            map.put("col_2",lastname[i]);
            fillMaps.add(map);
        }

        // fill in the grid_item layout
        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, fillMaps, R.layout.mainitem, from, to);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

create mainitem.xml file having two TextView which id are 1)R.id.firstname, 2) R.id.lastname in layout horizontal orientation

Comment: thanx for your valuable answer. I am using the same idea in other activity where i am using array list. In array list i cant get the length. How can i do this....

Answer (score 0):

As per the snap you have attached in the question, you need to define the custom listview adapter for the same.

For defining a custom row with 2 columnar output, you need to define an xml layout file containing 2 textviews side by side. Don't be confused, [just go through this example](http://pareshnmayani.wordpress.com/2011/06/10/android-%E2%80%93-listview-%E2%80%93-2-custom-listview/). In this example you need to modify the row layout file. Make a row file as such two textviews will be displayed side by side.

Answer (score 0):

Create a bean to store data

### Example

```
public class NameDetails {
    String firstName = null;
    String middleName = null;
NameDetails(String firstName, String middleName){
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.middleName=middleName;
}
String getFirstName(){
    return firstName;
}
String getMiddleName(){
    return middleName;
}
}
```

Add data to that bean using

```
NameDetails name1 = new NameDetails("arun","kumar");
..
...
```

Create array of Bean Objects. use this array for listview

```
{name1 , name2, name3, name4}
```

Answer (score -1):

Are you looking for [`notifyDataSetChanged()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29)?

Comment: no...Actually the data get changed whenever i open and close the activity

Comment: @Siva K so what do u want actually...you have already created the custom ListView.